# How to delete Change notification in Oracle

Tags: oracle

How to delete change notification in Oracle?

```
Delete from user_change_notification_regs
```

And return is

```
SQL Error: ORA-02030: can only select from fixed tables/views
```

Is there a way to delete the change notification?

Comment: As a more general comment rather than something specific to change notifications ***NEVER attempt to delete from a system table***. I cannot state this strongly enough.

Comment: Meaning that there is no way to delete it? @Ben

Comment: Delete a notification, or a registration? Are you trying to do a controlled deregistration from within your application, or clean up after a crash - and what timeout do the registrations have?

Comment: Meaning that you, personally, should not delete from the system tables @kingjia. There are usually methods that Oracle provides to delete things where it is necessary. Don't type `delete from...`

Comment: Hi @AlexPoole, try to deregister it..Because the timeout is infinite... But the problem is solved if the database is restart...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use DBMS_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION.DEREGISTER package?

Answer (score 1):

First look at here

```
select * from dba_change_notification_regs;
```

Get REGID and execute the following statement with REGID of the change notification that you want deregister.

```
execute DBMS_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION.DEREGISTER(1);
```

In this example REGID=1